# C# Problems while calculating Letter Frequency percentage

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, frequency

I am very unskilled in programming and I am trying to finish this task for my class. I've looked all over the Internet but still can't find the answer.

Here I have a piece of my code which prints out letters and the number of times it was spotted in my text file:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < (int)char.MaxValue; i++)
    {

        if (c[i] > 0 &&
            char.IsLetter((char)i))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Letter: {0}  Frequency: {1}",
                (char)i,
                c[i]);
        }
```

I've calculated the number of letters in my code using  int count = s.Count(char.IsLetter);
Dividing the c[i], obviously, doesn't work. I've tried several other methods but I keep getting errors. I feel like the solution is very simple but I simply can't see it. I hope that you will be willing to help me out :)

Comment: What is the type of `c` in your code?

Comment: As it's just a homework, I won't answer it, but here is just hint: I guess that the variable `c` is an array of integers which is full of zeroes at the beginning. It should be a memory of number of occurence for an algorithm. Then make the algorithm. you know that algorithm - Count number of letter "a" in this comment and use your fingers as the memory. (I see, I'm too late, somebody posted solution, but make the algorithm your way, not just copy - paste)

Comment: Don't you just need `c[i]/(double)c.Sum()`?

Comment: int[] c = new int[(int)char.MaxValue];

Comment: I think I fixed it with c[i] /(double)/count*100, it shows correct percentage now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dictionary to store the frequency of each letter. You also shouldn't loop with the constraint `i < (int)char.MaxValue`. This will put you out of bounds unless `c`'s length is >= `char.MaxValue`.

```
var frequency = new Dictionary<char, int>();
for (var i = 0; i < c.Length; i++)
{
    var current = (char)c[i];
    if (current > 0 && char.IsLetter(current))
    {
        if (!frequency.ContainsKey(current))
            frequency.Add(current);
        frequency[current]++;
        Console.WriteLine("Letter: {0}  Frequency: {1}", current, frequency[current]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `AddKey`? Will it add a key-value pair (only) if it is not there already?

Comment: Was just guessing what the method would be - I haven't written any C# in awhile. It was basically just a placeholder while I went and looked up the documentation quick.

Comment: Do you know what `c` is? A string? _Edit:_ After your changed code, `frequency[current]++` will (first) call the `get` accessor of the indexer (in `Dictionary<,>`), and that will throw an exception if the key is not already present (and you never add any keys).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Fixed.

Comment: Is there an overload for `Add` taking one argument only? No. If you need to solve the problem instead of finding out what the question is, why not just `s.Where(char.IsLetter).GroupBy(x => x).Select(x => $"Letter: {x.Key}  Count: {x.Count()}")` where `s` is the input of type `string`?

Comment: `I am very unskilled in programming and I am trying to finish this task for my class.` I don't know about you, but that would have made me even more confused as a beginner. The sheer fact that this code might not compile is even better because then the OP is going to have to understand the code more to be able to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have an integer division when you want a floating point division? In that case, cast either the dividend or the divisor to `double` (the other one will be converted automatically), for example:

```
(double)c[i] / count
```

**Edit:** Since you write *percentage*, if you need to multiply by one hundred, you can also make sure that literal is a `double`, then if you are careful with the precedence of the operators, you can have all casts implicit. Example:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Letter: {(char)i}  Count: {c[i]}  Percentage {c[i] * 100.0 / count}");
```

The multiplication goes first because of left-associativity. The literal `100.0` has type `double`.